# Getting transformed vertices back from the GPU in DirectX 10/11

Tags: c++, vertex, directx-11, directx-10, vertex-shader

The graphics engine I am developing has developed a major bottleneck which is matrix transforms on vertices (nearly no static vertices at all). So far I've been transforming the vertices with the CPU and updating the vertex buffer every frame (the data copying is a little bottleneck by itself but so far managable).

So I was thinking if I could just keep the mesh buffer inside the GPU, I could transform the vertices there and get that transformed set of vertices back to main memory for other processing (the subsequent processing requires a bit more inter connectivity than the GPU shaders allow). The might eliminate the bottleneck in the current code.

Any tips on how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Look into the stream-output stage in DX11:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205121(v=vs.85).aspx

It allows you to attach a memory buffer (on the CPU or GPU) in which the results from the vertex shader (and possible geometry shader) are stored.

Comment: don't you know a way how to do the same thing in DirectX9 ?